Moderators pinning opinions on questions but deleting opposing ones
A moderator posted a comment on this question:

A reminder to the linguistic prescriptivists: Scientists don't own words, and the battle over the term "chemical-free" was, perhaps sadly, lost by them a couple of decades ago. When used in marketing, the marketing definition (approximately: "no artificial additives produced in lab conditions by chemical reactions") can be inferred.

I responded to this with:

@Oddthinking It's not linguistic prescriptivism to argue that scientific terminology from a scientific field - which chemical is - be used accurately. There's no such thing as a marketing definition, it's the pseudoscience definition. Chemical is a scientific word with a specific meaning, scientists rolling over to allow marketers to appropriate it over the last few decades is what's contributed so heavily to pseudoscience and the natural-unnatural false dichotomy in that time. It's ironic that skeptics.SE is less skeptical about misinformation than some of the Facebook pages I follow.

The moderator then "moved" my comments and all others disagreeing with his/her opinion to a chat, which for all intents and purposes is a deletion because it has the effect of leaving only his/her opinion visible on the question to gather upvotes and otherwise influence the answers and views of those who come to the question (many of those coming to the question will read the comments, but very few will go on to read the chats).
I then commented one final time:

@Oddthinking Why have you deleted all the comments disagreeing with you and kept yours up? If you're allowed to use the comments as a soapbox for your personal opinion - which your comment definitely is, however you want to spin it - why do you not allow anyone else to respond to you with theirs?

The moderator moved this comment too and responded in the chat:

I moved them to chat because repeating an age-old debate from people who don't understand linguistics isn't the purpose of comments.

So now not only is the moderator's idea of linguistic prescriptivism influencing the question's answers and comments, it is also the only acceptable form of linguistics and anyone who doesn't agree with it "doesn't understand linguistics". I didn't know linguistic prescriptivist fundamentalists were a real thing before this interaction.
Does Skeptics.SE allow its moderators to use the comments as their own personal soapbox like this? In this case a good case can be made that this is active disinformation, caused by the moderator's over-reliance on (his opinion of) linguistics and overconfidence that this is the only opinion that can be held, and I would have expected more, well, skepticism from this stack site.

The moderator's behavior is strange, as is their long answer below which doesn't address the question.. as is the fact that this question is being downvoted.    See my comment on that answer below.

Some places are appropriate for some discussions. Some places are inappropriate. A large role of the moderator is encouraging and/or enforcing that only on-topic discussions happen in each forum.

Here are some places where we can discuss modern linguistics:
Linguistics.SE
I would suggest asking "Is it linguistic prescriptivism to argue that terminology be used according the scientific dictionaries (rather than common vernacular) in marketing material?" or "Why do modern linguists eschew linguistic prescriptivism?", but check for duplicates first.
Skeptics.SE chat
This channel was created precisely for that.

Here are some places where we can discuss how to construct an argument:
Philosopy.SE
I would suggest asking "Is it a logical fallacy to argue a written proposition is false, because I have a differing preference of the definitions of the terms used?" or "Why is it bad to rely on a strawman argument?", but again, check for duplicates first
Skeptics.SE chat
This channel was created precisely for that.

Here are some places where we shouldn't have extended discussion about linguistics and philosophy:
Comments under a question
They are intended for clarifying the question.
Meta Questions about policy.
So, I am not going to discuss linguistics and philosophy in depth here.

Here are some places we shouldn't use strawman and other logical fallacies to attack claims:
Answers to Skeptics.SE questions.
Comments to Skeptics.SE questions.
My warning comment remains because there was plenty of early evidence of commenters and answerers starting to lean on fallacies rather than address the actual claim, as intended by the claimant, and as understood by most of the readers of the claim.

As always, if you think a moderator is behaving poorly, please use the Contact link at the bottom of the page.

This answer doesn't address the question at all.  I don't think anyone has a problem with you moving the discussion to chat-- the problem is that you're repeatedly ignoring peoples' requests for you to move your comment about linguistic prescriptivism to the chat, after saying "Comments about linguistic prescriptivism have been moved to chat" and copying (not moving) your comment there.  I've flagged your comment for removal, and asked you twice to remove it, as have two other people.  Why are you not simply removing it?

I guess if you keep ignoring the requests to remove your now-inappropriate comment, we could escalate and use your "As always, if you think a moderator is behaving poorly, please use the Contact link at the bottom of the page.".  If we decide we care enough.    But honestly I am baffled as to why it's coming to that.  Why aren't you simply removing the comment?

(Re-reading, I'll retract "I don't think anyone has a problem with you moving the discussion to chat"-- I'll just say that I don't have a problem with that part. My problem is only with you leaving your own comment there while moving the other comments. I.e. the title of this meta question.)

@DonHatch: Please see the chat. The short version: I reject the loaded question because of the hidden premise that this is a matter of two equally valid opinions clashing, rather than a consilience of philosophers of argument and modern linguists versus an indefensible position.

I echo Don Hatch's sentiments about this "answer" - it's a patronising non-answer which once again seeks to tell everyone disagreeing how wrong they are, how only your opinion is the correct one and why it should therefore be the only one visible on the question.

Even if we take you at your word of what "true" linguistic prescriptivism is: 1. there isn't a single site rule that says that linguists determine the validity of answers or comments; 2. linguistic descriptivism is a single school of thought in linguistics, not the divine linguistic scripture that you seem to think of it as. This entire bizarre conversation reminds me of conversations with religious fundamentalists, and - irrespective of how true it might or might not be - using it as a basis for controlling the content on a Skeptics.SE question is a blatant abuse of moderator powers.

And even though the answer would be completely immaterial to this meta question for the reasons given above, I went ahead and asked this anyway: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/49288/is-it-linguistic-prescriptivism-to-argue-that-jargon-should-be-used-accurately.

@Prometheus: I don't wish to have the debate about prescriptivism here. It is the wrong place. There is a chat set aside for it. Meanwhile, you are calling for a false balance; I reject you painting it as an equivalent opinion.
